# How do I check if a python module has been imported?

Tags: python

For example, I import json like so `import json` and now somewhere in the code I want to check if it has been imported. It should be something like: `has_imported(module_name)`.

The reason why I'm asking this is because I'm trying to understand how `pkgutil.walk_packages()` works. It must import the modules it lists but for some reason some modules are not imported. Seems like I have to import them with a separate function but first this function needs to "know" whether a module that it gets as an argument was imported or not.

There are some similar questions, but I'm far from being satisfied with the answers.

Comment: If you write `import json` at the top of your file, then you can be pretty sure it's imported in that file. That does not mean it will be imported *everywhere* (in other files). Might that be a cause of confusion here? Or are you trying to figure out whether any one package has generally been imported by any other module somewhere? (If so, what for?)

Comment: If you want to know how `pkgutil.walk_packages()` works, why not [just look at its source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b9c3da5c89c66dcccf382e8f196746da2a06d4cc/Lib/pkgutil.py#L53-L107)?

Comment: @deceze No, it's not. I import modules with `walk_packages` (as far as I understand it imports modules on the fly) but some modules in the list don't seem to be imported. I'm just trying to figure out why,

Comment: Then you might rather want to ask a concrete question about that…?

Comment: @deceze I'd already done that before asking this one but no one answered...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test for the module name in the [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules) dictionary:

```
import sys

print("sys" in sys.modules) #True
print("datetime" in sys.modules) #False
print("json" in sys.modules) #False
```

Comment: In the interactive mode all of them return `True`. How is that?

Comment: @Foobard, try to open another instance of command line (or what else you are using). I just checked it in my terminal (ver Python 3) - datetime and json checks return False

Comment: I've just checked it in my terminal too and yeah now it works as expected. I wonder why it didn't in that terminal. I'm 100% certain I didn't import the modules I checked.